# Linking HTML to CSS file

Tags: html, css

I have a problem linking an HTML file "index.html" to my CSS file "stylesheet.css". I've pasted the same code in from CodeAcademy and w3schools in, but none of them work. I'm using Notepad++ - is it a problem with the software? I've attached the first section of my code. They are both saved in the same folder.

```
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title>Fred's Present</title>
</head>
```

Thanks!

Comment: "but none of them work" can you expand on this? how is it not working? are you getting 404 errors in your console?

Comment: This is too little information. The basic example you described should work. Please link to some active code.

Comment: In this case provide your project tree (all the file that are include in the file you use to open your website/webapps).

Comment: Your stylesheet is in the root?

Comment: can you trouble shoot the situation wit your browser, maybe? for example, hit ctrl+shift+J in firefox and enable network logging, then reload the page. What does it say? Does the path to the stylesheet appear to be correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<title>Fred's Present</title>
</head>
```

your code is absolutely fine...you must have kept your css file in some other folder.
try to keep both the files in the same folder so that your linking can work properly.

Comment: You could have improved your answer by providing hints in case the file is in another directory.

Comment: From the OP's question: "They are both saved in the same folder."

Comment: Hi, it's OK there was an issue with the CSS, that's why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine... maybe you put the css file in another folder or you have the css file on a USB stick. In this case, you should have, for example:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\file\file\stylesheet.css">
<title>Fred's Present</title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is absolutely OK, maybe you've kept the file on a SDD or on a USB stick. But to be sure, you should type:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="D:\My Programs\myfile.css">
```